# Convert OO to Procedural

Tags: php

Been a while since I last posted here, but I need some help!

First, I am creating a messaging system and I copied it from a tutorial (I like to copy code to use and study) but it's in what I believe is Object Orientated version (correct me if I'm wrong). I only use the procedural version, none of those "->" or anything. How can I convert this into procedural?

```
$grab_pm = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `pms` WHERE `touser` = '$touser' AND `id` = '$id'");

while($r= mysqli_fetch_object($grab_pm)) {


echo "<h2>$r->subject</h2>";
echo "<p>$r->message</p>";
echo "<p>From: $r->fromuser ";
echo "<p>On: $r->datesent</p>";
```

Thanks!

I see it is just changing to this

```
while($r= mysqli_fetch_array($grab_pm)) {
$subject = $r['subject'];
$message = $r['message'];
$fromuser = $r['fromuser'];
$datesent = $r['datesent'];

echo "<h2>$subject</h2>";
echo "<p>$message</p>";
echo "<p>From: $fromuser ";
echo "<p>On: $datesent</p>";
```

Comment: This is not OO, it's just mysql_fetch_object instead of mysql_fetch _assoc probably. Could you show more code as to where these variables are instantiated?

Comment: This tiny last bit is probably the least to worry about. You'll have to rewrite all the code that comes before this so you won't even have any sort of object at this particular point. We obviously can't tell you how to do that. Or you could, you know, learn a little about OOP.

Comment: @Rik_S My bad, what should I change the title to? And I've added more code

Comment: But do you see what you have done there: You have turned 4 lines of code into 8 lines of code. Created 4 unnecessary scalar variiables which have to be allocated on the stack. Then you move 4 pieces of data from one perfectly good array into the 4 new scalar variables. Then you output the data as before. Now there are 4 entries on the stack that will continuue to use space for no good reason until the script finishes. What was wrong with addressing the row returned from the query as an object. If you want to copy other peoples code in order to learn new things, why not _learn new things_

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's just 4 extra lines of code, how it's going, I write the code then come back and optimise it later (when I'm better at coding). I would understand it's not the best way if I'm writing a program for a business, but I'm not :)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch associative array instead of object:

```
$grab_pm = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `pms` WHERE `touser` = '$touser' AND `id` = '$id'");

while($r= mysqli_fetch_assoc($grab_pm)) {

   echo "<h2>$r['subject']</h2>";
   echo "<p>$r['message']</p>";
   echo "<p>From: $r['fromuser'] ";
   echo "<p>On: $r['datesent']</p>";
}
```

But I still highly suggest you learn a thing or two about OOP, even though you think it's an obsolete non-sence :)